# Cord Tension sensor

Tags: sensor, servo

I need to detect when the tension in a (micro) winch cord either exceeds or falls below maximum or minimum tension.  The winch is powered by a stepper or servo motor and the intent is to back off when snagged and to take up the slack.

I could assemble something involving a pulley suspended from a spring, but I'm hoping there is a better alternative.  The cord will be 3lb test monofilament and the total load will be on the order of 20 gms.

Comment: Hello. Sorry to say that it's not clear to me how this is directly related to the Raspberry Pi nor how a normal load cell or strain gauge sensor between your winch and it's mounting point would not work. Can you elaborate?